# Find all solutions of the congruence $x^3 - 3x + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod {25}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, binomial-theorem

I know that the above problem is equivalent to:

$x^3 - 3x + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod {5^2}$

So:
Let $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 2$ and $f'(x) = 3x^2 - 3$

1. Solve for: $f(x) = x^3 - 3x + 2 \equiv 0 \pmod {5}$

-> $x_1 = 1 + 5k_1$ (found 1 as a soln mod 5)

Lift $x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod {5}$ $\iff$ $x_1 = 1 + 5k_1$

$\iff$ By Binomial $f(x_2) = f(1 + 5k_1)$ $= f(1) + f'(1)5k_1$ $(mod5^2)$

I do not know how to proceed from here because I get $0mod5^2$ after evaluating the above.

Please advise. Also let me know if there is a polynomial congruence calculator of which I can use to check my work for similar questions. This is the only one I found: https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUADMOD.HTM

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E3+-+3+x+%2B+2+%3D+0+mod+25+

Comment: Note:  besides $1$ that you said you found, $3$ is also a solution, mod $5$

Answer (score 2):

I would simply factor the polynomial as $(x-1)^2(x+2)$.  The $(x-1)^2$ factor is zero whenever $x\equiv  1\bmod 5$, and $x+2\equiv 0$ gives an additional solution $\bmod 25$.  Since not both factors can be multiples of $5$, this exhausts the possibilities giving the solution set $\{1,6,11,16,21,23\}$.

Comparing this result with your method we see what happened when $x\equiv 1\bmod 5$.  Because all corresponding residues and not just one residue $\bmod 25$ are admitted with that $(x-1)^2$ factor, the Hensel lifting method does not discriminate when you go up to $\bmod 25$.  You lift $x\equiv 1\bmod 5$ to *all*  $5k+1$ residues $\bmod 25$.  To get any discrimination you have to go at least to the next power of $5$, $\bmod 125$, which you do not do here.

Comment: You can also use that $x^3-3x\equiv -((-x)^3-3(-x))$